# TypeScript interface with spread members

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm bulk importing a bunch of properties with

`import * as actionCreators from './billingUtil2';`

and TypeScript is correctly identifying each export inside of `actionCreators`.  Is it possible to "spread" those members into an interface?  Ideally something like this, but valid

```
interface componentState {
    ...actionCreators
}
```

---

My use case is, I'd like to create a React component and accurately describe the shape of the props it'll be receiving from Redux.  So ideally something along these lines

```
import * as actionCreators from './billingUtil2';

interface State {
    name: string;
    age: number
}

interface componentState extends State {
    ...actionCreators
}
```

and then I could tell TypeScript to expect props of the form `componentState`. 
 My redux reducers would already be returning results implementing an interface; my main goal here is to avoid manually typing out each action creator.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could create an [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```
import * as actionCreators from './billingUtil2';

type MyState = typeof actionCreators & {
    name: string
    age: number
}
```

or from your code in the second section above, where you had the `State` interface, you could do

```
import * as actionCreators from './billingUtil2';

interface State {
    name: string;
    age: number
}

type componentShape = typeof actionCreators & State;
```

or you could similarly do

```
type acT = typeof actionCreators
interface MyState extends acT {
    name; age;
}

class Comp extends React.Component<{}, MyState> {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Intersection Type, proposed in the accepted answer works for most of uses cases.

But let's pretend (a very common use case) that actionCreators type already has `name` property but it is different type.

```
interface ActionCreators {
  name: string[]; // list of strings which may include 1st to last name
  gender: string;
  height: number;
}
```

Then you will get errors saying that ActionCreators and State aren't compatible.

To fix this you could use [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), to remove the name from ActionCreators, before using intersection type strategy.

```
// Remove the 'name' property
type RemoveNameField<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as Exclude<Property, "name">]: Type[Property]
};
 
type State = RemoveNameField<ActionCreators> & { name: string; age: number; };
```